# how to get rid of arm64 in apt

Tags: 16.04, apt, nvidia

```
W: Invalid 'Date' entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/_var_cuda-repo-8-0-local_Release
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

After I installed Jetpack for Jetson tx1, my ubuntu constantly tries to fetch arm updates. Is there a way to disable this?

EDIT:

```
$dpkg --print-architecture
amd64

$dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
arm64
```

I see that arm64 is included in foreign architectures. How do I remove it?

Comment: Please add the output of `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`.

Comment: I faced the same problem. this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295241/dpkg-error-cannot-remove-architecture-i386-currently-in-use-by-the-database) helped me removing my arm64 packages. and then used the solution given by byte commander

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can remove a foreign architecture by running

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm64
```

After that, you need to update your software lists.

```
sudo apt update
```

---

If you still get some errors or warnings, you can try deleting all your software lists and completely re-downloading them from the server, to make sure nothing old is left. Note that the complete download will take a bit longer than usual:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo apt update
```

Comment: I get `dpkg: error: cannot remove architecture 'arm64' currently in use by the database` which is odd because i don't think i'm using it...

Comment: @MoneyBall Can you add the output of `dpkg -l | grep arm64` to your question? Seems like some arm64 packages are installed, which you would have to remove first.

Comment: ah crap... I have arm64 cross compiler...  but I successfully removed armhf which was a pain. Thank you.

Comment: do you know how i can make apt-get update to stop fetching arm64 packages? How do i get rid of those 404 not found errors?

Comment: They will be gone as soon as the arm64 architecture is removed. I don't know if you can tell apt to not check for these repositories otherwise.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the arm64 from the database, I'm having the same issues. *EDIT* `sudo dpkg --force-architecture --remove-architecture arm64` and `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists` with `sudo apt update` fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

Faced same issue while working with jetson-tx2 arm64.
This [manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#advanced-setup) refers the solution in advanced setup scenario
It turns out you can't remove architecture without removing packages.

This is useful when a foreign architecture has been added, causing "404 Not Found" errors to appear when the repository meta-data is updated.
For example, if you wanted to restrict a repository to only the amd64 and i386 architectures, it would look like:

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] <url>
```

Provide the above option for all repositories in "sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list"

Now "sudo apt update" and it will fetch only from amd64 and i386.

Comment: This worked for me on 18.04.2.  Thank you!  Wish I could upvote twice :) .

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and as Byte Commander mentioned if you cant directly run

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm64
```

You have have bunch of cross-compile arm64 packages installed and need to run this before removing arm64. Run the following commands in the order listed:

```
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm64
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. I was not able to `apt update`, nor to `apt upgrade`, because arm64 Package updates failed in 404 Error.

`dpkg` gave me the output:

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
arm64
```

Looking at my installed arm64 packages showed that there was some cross-compiling stuff installed by Jetpack:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep arm64
ii  cuda-cudart-cross-aarch64-9-0:arm64  9.0.252-1           arm64   CUDA Runtime cross-aarch64 dev links, headers
ii  libc6-arm64-cross                    2.23-0ubuntu3cross1 all     GNU C Library: Shared libraries (for cross-compiling)
ii  linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross           4.4.0-18.34cross1   all     Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
...
```

**My solution:**

I just ran the Jetpack Uninstaller, which cleared all those cross-compiling packages as well as the arm64 architecture:

```
$ ./JetPack_Uninstaller
```

Afterwards I was able again to use `apt` properly.

Comment: Where's the `JetPack_Uninstaller` located?