# 16.04 Update/upgrade failing - Resources not found

Tags: upgrade, updates

I'm trying to upgrade a 16.04 system.  When I do:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get:

```
 Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc6-dbg amd64 2.23-0ubuntu9  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

and many more like it.

I did `sudo apt-get update`, but got similar messages:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

Output of --print-architecture:

```
amd64
```

Output of --print-foreign-architectures:

```
i386
arm64
```

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Please use the `{}` button in the editor (or four spaces at the front of the line) to format terminal blocks.

Comment: Please add the outputs of `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` to your question.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex - Added info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get rid of arm64 in apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917081/how-to-get-rid-of-arm64-in-apt)

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex - removing the arm64 did fix the problem.   However, would like to get it working with the arm64 foreign architecture.

Comment: You can add the architecture back in with `sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64`, then add `[arch=amd64,i386]` immediately after all `deb`s (not `deb-src`s) that complain in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. That restricts those specific lines to those specific architectures, leaving out `arm64`. An example line would be `deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change which mirror I get updates and software from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53084/how-do-i-change-which-mirror-i-get-updates-and-software-from)