# sudo apt-get update gets Universe, but cannot find any files in it

Tags: 16.04, apt

I've gone through the duplicates here and I cannot find how to fix this problem; basically none of the core repositories update, but third-party ones do, on the whole.

For instance, I want to install the [`bats` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/bats), so I can see the line in `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Get:23 http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [7,532 kB]
```

I presume this is OK, even though at the end I get:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/Packages
    404 Not Found
```

And also for `xenial-updates` and `xenial-security`, but the text says "They have been ignored, or old ones used instead." Note that the main site and random mirrors all fail.

Now, `apt list *bats*` reports merely `libatspi2.0-0`.

Third-party repositories (Opera and ROS, for instance) work fine, but what could be causing my problem with the official repositories? I'm also not getting any updates from there.

Note that when I work with Docker, `Dockerfile` `RUN apt-get` works as expected, so it's probably not some network or quota issue.

Comment: `arm64`? I don't think that mirror has any arm64 files.

Comment: Yes, I'm not interested in `arm64`, so that's why I said I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: If you're not interested in arm64, why do you have it enabled? Remove it https://askubuntu.com/a/917086/158442

Comment: I've got some CUDA cross-compiler stuff installed - I'll uninstall and see what happens.

Comment: Wow! That worked.